# Magento 1.9.x: How to change the system so that new orders start from a specific number going up?

Tags: sales-order

Magento 1.9.4

We just created a brand new Magento store and are going to switch our existing domain to that but we would like to change the order numbers in such a way that the new orders placed would start from the number where we left of on our old Magento 1.9.1 system.

Is there an easy way to do that? We have access to the database via phpMyAdmin in Cpanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this one. This might help you about [changing the starting order number in Magento 1.x](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Admin-Configuration/Can-I-change-the-starting-order-number/m-p/17550#M779)